# How to define schema in graphql query for unknown or dynamic response

Tags: graphql

I am new to graphQL and want to know how to define a schema for a response that changes with respect to input field.

For example, i defined my response class as

```
typealias studentResponse = HashMap<String, String>
```

Based on student id, my response will vary like,

```
{ studentDetails(studentId:1234){
      chemistry,
      maths,
  }
}
```

but some student id may return other extra unknown key value pairs like language,physics etc etc.

May i know how can i run the query and get the result dynamically in graphQl without defining in schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should avoid "generic" key-value pairs in your graphql schema, because you than loose the typesafety. I think this is one of the reasons, why there is no Map type in GraphQL.

In your case, you may could use a [union type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types) for your result instead.

If you really need something more generic, you could use an array with a tuple-like object inside, like so:

```
type Tuple {
  name: String!
  value: String!
}

type StudentDetails {
  # ...
  additionalValues: [Tuple!]
}
```

(See also this discussion: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/101#issuecomment-170170967.)

Another option: specify all possible returned fields from all different student types and mark them as optional (nullable):

```
type StudentResponse {
  # common for ALL students (required, non-nullable)
  chemistry: String!
  maths: String!

  # optional, returned only for some students
  language: String
  physics: String
}
```

Hope that helps!